# Can you OR multiple filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a couple of different custom filters.  In an ng-repeat I would like to filter results based on one filter or the other, not both filters.

I understand there is a fundamental flaw here in that I think these filters are applied in a pipeline so 'ORing' filters really doesn't make sense.

Wondering how to achieve this?

Example:

Filter to match on any part of users name (first + last)

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('fullname', function() {
  return function(users, search) {
    var match = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    return users.filter(function (user) {
      var fullname = user.firstname + " " + user.lastname;
      if (match.test(fullname)) return true;
    });
  };
});
```

Filter to match on email. Simple don't really need it as I can use filter: {email: param}.

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('email', function() {
  return function(users, search) {
    var match = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    return users.filter(function (user) {
      if (match.test(user.email)) return true;
    });
  };
});
```

In one partial I only care to match on full name, works great:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="user in users | fullname:query>
```

In another I match only on email (perfect):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="user in users | email:query>
```

OR (without custom email):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{email: query}>
```

But can I use the filters I already have to match on multiple?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="user in users | fullname:query | filter: {email: query}>
```

Problem here is that the fullname filter is applied and then the email filter is applied.  Is there a different way I can do this to get it to match either fullname OR email not AND?

I know in the end I can write another filter to filter fullname OR email.  But what happens when I want a 3rd, 4th or 5th.  Don't really want to write all bunch of custom filters that are one offs.

Ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can.. <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter1 | filter2 | filter3" >

Comment: That will AND not OR.  Meaning if I do: user in users | fullname:query | email: query   if query is 'Foo' that would have to be in both fullname and email.  Not fullname OR email.

Comment: [Here is a good reference](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/filters/chaining-filters-together.html) what you're doing with | is chaining, not ORing.

Comment: @PatrickMotard sorry for the confusion.  I know its chaining, sorry I called it a pipeline.  So I get why it does not work.  My question is how can I achieve OR filter not chain them, because chaining is not what I want.

Comment: Do you want the user to designate which search filter to use? How is the outcome of the or being determined?